# Swift - String substringWithRange - 'String' is not convertible to '()'

Tags: string, swift, compiler-errors

I am trying some simple code, which I found on [natashatherobot.com](http://natashatherobot.com/swift-string-substringinrange/).

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

let rangeOfHello = Range(start: str.startIndex, end: advance(str.startIndex, 5))
let helloStr = str.substringWithRange(rangeOfHello)
return helloStr
```

It works fine when I try it in *Playgrounds*:

[image: Playground]

But when I try using it in my *Xcode* project it gives me a compilation error:

[image: Xcode Project]

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function declaration you are saying that it returns a void, but you are trying to return a string, You need to add the `-> String` in the end of your function to match what you are trying to do

your function:

```
func getStringBetween(startString: String, endString: String) -> ()
```

shoud be:

```
func getStringBetween(startString: String, endString: String) -> String
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify the return type of your `func`:

```
func getStringBetween(startString: String, endString: String) -> String {
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the method `getStringBetween(:endString:)`, which you defined in your `extension` for `String`.
This method does not define a return type (there's no `-> Type` after the parameter list). Therefore the implicit return type is `Void`, so your method could be written as:

```
func getStringBetween(startString: String, endString: String) -> Void
```

In Swift the type `Void` is equivalent to an empty tuple `()`.

The problem is therefore that Swift expects a return type of `Void` denoted by `()`, but you're returning a `String`.
This problem is easily fixed by adding the return type `String` to the declaration of your method:

```
func getStringBetween(startString: String, endString: String) -> String
```

Side Note:
When writing `return`, without a specification of what is to be returned, Swift automatically returns `()`.